# how to put custom list view inside fragments??fragments are a part of a view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

is there any way of doing this without extending the class to "ListFragment"?i don't wan't to use Listfragments because then i will have to change myviewpager adapter..but if there is no choice left i will have to :(  .Also i tried using Listfragments but i was unable to make the listfragments a part of viewpager,in other words, i was unable to populate Listfragments in a viewpager,

this is just a part of code showing how i populated fragments

```
   List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentSongs.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentArtists.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentPlaylists.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentAlbums.class.getName())); 


            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);


            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
```

is their any parallel code to this, that can be used for listfragments?

```
here is the code:




  package sourcecode.jazzplayer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter{
    public boolean accept(File dir,String name)
    {

    return (name.endsWith(".mp3"))|| (name.endsWith(".Mp3")) ||(name.endsWith(".MP3"));//searching for the files
    }
}
public class FragmentSongs extends  Fragment {

    private static final String Sd_Path=new String("/sdcard/");
    //setting up the source path

    //private MediaPlayer mp =new MediaPlayer();




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //  updatePlaylist() ;
        //updatePlaylist();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        ListView SngList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.SongList);

         SongDetails Detail = null;
         Context _c = null ;



           ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo;
             // AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
              Songinfo = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();

            File home=new File(Sd_Path);
            if(home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length>0)
            {
                for(File file:home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()))
                {
                 Detail.setSong(file.getName());
                 Detail.setArtist(file.getName());
                 Detail.setAlbum(file.getName());
                 Songinfo.add(Detail);

                 SngList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Songinfo , _c));


                }
            }
        return view;


    } }




    /*private void updatePlaylist()
    {
         SongDetails Detail = null ;
         Context _c = null ;
           ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo;
          AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
          Songinfo = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();

        File home=new File(Sd_Path);
        if(home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length>0)
        {
            for(File file:home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()))
            {
             Detail.setSong(file.getName());
             Detail.setArtist(file.getName());
             Detail.setAlbum(file.getName());
             Songinfo.add(Detail);

             SngList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Songinfo , _c));


            }
        }
    }

}

        */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's possible.
If you don't want to use a ListFragment, you need to add a custom id (android:id="@+id/custom_id") then you can use findViewById to find the ListView

--edit
So instead of:

```
       //ListView   SngList = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.SongList);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
```

you should do:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
ListView sngList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.SongList);
return view;
```

it's just one thing which I've noticed.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/
look at 1.3. "ListView example " there is ListView in regular Activity. Instead of Activity it can be in Fragment

Comment: But i tried putting a list in it and it didn't work,the app crashed while running

Comment: ok i will in about 40 mins,if you are online please do reply, i am in college right now

Comment: i have provided the code above,please have a look,i don't know what should i put in "context"

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: hey i have one more question 
in the line 
SngList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Songinfo , _c)); 
here i don't know what "_c" is,in the class custom adapter,one of the arguments was "context" so i created a context '_c' and passed it, i tried "this"but it didn't work

Comment: follow tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/#listview_listviewexample

Comment: Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //  updatePlaylist() ;
        //ListView   SngList = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.SongList);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);


    } 

(taking all the comments in this code as proper code and not comments)

when i call the function updateplaylist();
thats when the app crashes

Comment: if you're using this code with Fragment then it crashes. I wrote how to fix it in my answer above. Next time update code in your question, because comment is not the place for the code.

Comment: i have updated my code..please can you see whats the problem???? i appreciate the time you have given me,but i really need this badly

Comment: i have a feeling that there is a problem with the "context" i am passing

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, all you have to do is make your fragment have a ListView in it's layout.